# BLE : onConnectionStateChange Status 8 on Samsung phones

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a heart rate monitoring app where I am reading data from BLE device, for all other phones there is no issue but for Samsung mobile like Note 8, which uses Bluetooth version 5.0 It is auto disconnect after some time and I am getting status 8

**Code :**

**For connect**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      mGattClient = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallbacks, TRANSPORT_LE)
    } else {
      mGattClient = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallbacks)
    }
```

// **Connection state change**

```
override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
      when (newState) {
        BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED -> {
//           this sleep is here to avoid TONS of problems in BLE, that occur whenever we start
//           service discovery immediately after the connection is established
           mGattClient?.discoverServices()
        }
        BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED -> {
          Log.d(TAG,"Disconnected status"+ status)
        }
      }
    }

    // New services discovered
    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
      when (status) {
        BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> mListener?.deviceConnected(MESSAGE_CONNECTED, status)
        else -> Log.w("BLE", "onServicesDiscovered received: $status")
      }
    }
```

I have posted this on google issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122856771

Answer (score 9):

This issue has nothing to do with Android OS itself or your software. The error code 8 means Connection Timeout according to the Bluetooth specification. It means the Bluetooth hardware in the phone lost connection to the device. There are mainly three reasons: bad antenna / radio reception, clock drift between the two devices so they lose synchronization, too many scheduling conflicts (if you have multiple connections).

Is you experience that your Note 8 has significantly worse performance than other phones, send an issue report to Samsung.

Comment: So Is there any solution, I see this issue on some other Samsung phone as well, sometimes disabling the app optimization works, sometimes switching off the wifi while taking reading It works